# Inconsistency in `Varien_Object` exporting methods

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, varien

I've been studying the source code of Magento recently, and I came across this snippet in `Varien_Object`, which is puzzling me:

```
/**
 * Convert object attributes to array
 *
 * @param  array $arrAttributes array of required attributes
 * @return array
 */
public function __toArray(array $arrAttributes = array())
{
    if (empty($arrAttributes)) {
        return $this->_data;
    }

    $arrRes = array();
    foreach ($arrAttributes as $attribute) {
        if (isset($this->_data[$attribute])) {
            $arrRes[$attribute] = $this->_data[$attribute];
        }
        else {
            $arrRes[$attribute] = null;
        }
    }
    return $arrRes;
}

/**
 * Public wrapper for __toArray
 *
 * @param array $arrAttributes
 * @return array
 */
public function toArray(array $arrAttributes = array())
{
    return $this->__toArray($arrAttributes);
}
```

My understanding is that if I wanted an array of the data within a `Varien_Object`, I would call the `toArray()` method. But the impression I get from this code is that `__toArray()` should be private. Yet it is public.

Can anybody tell me if this is an oversight, or if __toArray is used somewhere else in the Magento codebase?

I thought that perhaps it is a legacy thing, but if that were true, wouldn't there be a note saying so?

### Update

This inconsistency gets stranger still. `Varien_Object` has many methods to export the data:

- `toArray()`
- `toXml()`
- `toJson()`
- `toString()`

Of these four, only `toArray()` has a corresponding public `__toArray()` method. `toXml()` and `toJson()` have protected ones, and `toString()` has none, except a commented out one, which was public.

On a separate note, Magento seems to use a public wrapper function quite a lot. `toHtml()` and `_toHtml()` spring to mind. Why is this? What advantage does using such a function provide when creating a subclass?

Answer (score 2):

It is used two times:

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Option.php:427
$newOption = $this->__toArray();

/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Option/Value.php:203
return $this->__toArray();
```

So it looks like whether they use it more ore less "protected".

Nevertheless, I think the intention behind the naminig `__toArray` is, that they want be similar to __toString() ignoring the circumstance, that it has no meaning within PHP. And `__toString` is public!

Comment: Thanks. This comment motivated me to look at the rest of the exporter methods in `Varien_Object`. See my update for what I found. They aren't consistent with each other at all. Presumably, as a client I'm supposed to ignore the __ methods and just used the unprefixed ones, but it still leaves me wondering about it all.

Comment: Wow. Ok. This is inconsistency. No idea :)

Comment: I guess if this is the only weird part in a six year old project the size of Magento, then that's remarkable. It does seem to be pretty clean considering both its age and size.